# Vertical line and point sign together in round brackets

Tags: notation

Recently I read the notaions like `q(a|.)` or `q(.|T)` in a pseudocode.
I try to find out its meaning and I found a lot of different usages of the vertical line and point respectively but not in one expression together.

In set theory `y(a|b)` means y function at value `a` such that `b` is true.
Another example from Wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_symbols :

> "`P(A|B)` means the probability of the event `A` occurring given that
>   `B` occurs".

But no reference to the `.` sign with the `|` sign together.

Could somebody please explain?

Comment: Can you give a link or reference to where you saw the notation you're asking about?

Comment: Usually the dot is used as a placeholder for the argument of the function.

Comment: @quasi I can give a longer citation

Comment: @DMcMor I thought about that, but obviously my bad I couldn't interpret it with the vertical line

Comment: @George Solymosi: Longer isn't necessary. Just more specific to the exact context. You said you've seen it "in pseudocode". Can you give a link or reference to where?

Comment: @quasi I found it: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1701.01724.pdf
Page 36

Comment: In this context, I think the "dot" stands for the random action selected, and the bar is the usual "given" as used in probability. So it's just a symbol which takes a value (i.e., it's a variable).

Comment: @quasi So you mean "any of the available actions"?
What is the difference when the point sign is prior and after the vertical line?

Comment: Before means "choose an action, given something (e.g., given $I$ (the information set)". After means "do something given the chosen action".

Comment: I wouldn't say the dot paired with a bar is a standard notation. Rather, it's the author's chosen notation, made clear from the context, and from the comments in the code.

Comment: @quasi That's clear now, thank you very much for your explanation!

Comment: @George Solymosi -- Looking at the code more carefully, I may be wrong about the dot being the chosen action. The variable "a" seems a better fit for that. I'm probably right that the bar means "given". Perhaps the dot refers to the set of available actions, rather than the chosen one.

Comment: @George Solymosi -- Since your question relates to a particular pseudocode,  perhaps ask it on one of the programming oriented stack exchanges. Alternatively, you  could email your question to one of the authors of the arxiv paper (the paper has ten authors).

Comment: I switched the tag to [tag:notation]. I didn't see any [tag:group-theory] in the question. If there is, please explain. If not, then all is now fine.